# Provider component doesn't re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am not actually sure whether it's expected behaviour and I am just missing something :)

Container file:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2b93241de5573bd0a6bd

This Game component is used as follows:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/80f0c2747c25a541e68d
After pickColor action is dispatched, store is updated (I checked by subscribing to it from other place). So after this action is dispatched - Game component doesn't re-render.

And as I said, I am not sure if I didn't set up redux properly or is it just designed in that way so I have to re-render component manually by subscribing to store?

Comment: If your store is being updated but your component isn't then it's likely that you're *mutating* your state. What does your reducer look like?

Comment: That was a problem. Stupid me. Thanks

Comment: Detailed answer added for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `react-redux` bindings will only update your components when the state object is a new object instance.

Thus your reducers must return brand new objects. This is what immutability is all about.

**BAD:**

```
switch (action.type) {
    case SET_VALUE:
        state.value = action.value;
        return state;
}
```

**GOOD:**

```
switch (action.type) {
    case SET_VALUE:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            value: action.value
        });
}
```

Comment: Oh man, I've been searching for about 2 hours now on why the heck my component's state wasn't being uploaded, checking react dev tools and seeing the new items appearing, checking my reducer function only to realize I was return the exact same state but only changing the single key on that state. Object.assign() for the win!

Thanks Mr Walsh... also, I love your blog, and the article about feeling like a fraud. cheers from Seattle! :)

Comment: It is indeed a great blog, just not one I can take credit for. (Different person, same name.) But otherwise, glad to be of help.